# Transaction Manager not showing storekit 2 transactions in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test in-app purchase localy using configuration.storekit file.
I'm able to do perform the fetch, buy, restore, etc on the simulator, but the same is not getting displayed on the Transaction Manager [(with Xcode selected) Debug->Storekit->Manage Transactions...]

Also, I am not able to fetch the products using product IDs in the testcases using StoreKitTest framework

I have use pod lib create to make a cocoapod of MyFramework which is having all the In-App purchase related code/logic. Have a target for testcases (MyFramework-Unit-Tests), have tried linking the StoreKit Configuration File with both the MyFramework and MyFramework-Unit-Tests targets, and without linking too

I have created a file IAPSubscriptions.storekit, and have tried specifying target to it - MyFramework, MyFramework-Unit-Tests

Has anyone faced these issues, and how shall I resolve these?

For reference:
Modularisation followed by me is wrt: https://github.com/kudoleh/iOS-Modular-Architecture
**My podfile has:**
def MyFramework_pod
pod 'MyFramework', :path => 'DevPods/MyFramework', :testspecs => ['Tests']
end

abstract_target 'MyFramework' do
project 'DevPods/MyFramework/Example/MyFramework.xcodeproj'
target 'MyFramework_Example' do
platform :ios, '15.0'
MyFramework_pod
end
end

**My podspec has:**
s.test_spec 'Tests' do |test_spec|
test_spec.source_files = 'MyFramework/Tests/**/*'
end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the StoreKit.framework as a dependency to the app project.

In Xcode, this capability is known as "In-App Purchase".

Comment: Also, if you are developing a cocoapod for IAP, then I had to add StoreKit.framework to the host/Sample app and adding StoreKit.framework merely to the cocoapod didn't work